# How to sort by descending nested Dictionary in C# using LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, dictionary

I need some help to sort by descending nested Dictionary which is quite hard for me because I'm not so advanced , I've been searching many sites but with no success. If someone can give me a hand with this I'll be grateful. So here is the code

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>> champLeague = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>>();
```

For example when I add -

Barcelona, Arsenal, 1

Man Unted, Liverpool, 2

Man City, Stoke City, 3

And I want to print out the dictionary ordered by descending by the second dictionary's value like this :

```
var orderedDic = champLeague.OrderByDescending(x => x.Value.Values).ThenBy(x => x.Value.Keys)
```

And try `foreach(var kvp in orderedDic){Console.WriteLine(kvp.Key)}`
It throws me an exception : "unhandled exception at least one object must be implemented IComparable"

I want to look like this :

Man City

Man United

Barcelona

Comment: A dictionary is for look ups, however you can use it like any other IEnumerable.  But How are you trying to out put your data?  you example is no versatile enough. What if the same value is added to both dictionaries how should they be displayed? e.g `Barcelona, Arsenal, 1
 Man United, Liverpool, 1` do you want to list these in a row or should you merge all of the dictionaries and their values?

Comment: *For example when I add ...* - we are all programmers here, you could post some code rather than listing some data which is unclear where it goes.

Comment: From your problem statement, I can understand that you want to sort out the matches with respect to the number of goals. And for each team pair there will be number of goals. Am I right?

Comment: It sound like you're using a dictionary to avoid creating a class, which contains city, team, and rank

Comment: Ok here is the full code with comments if you want to take a look - https://pastebin.com/rivgGsWE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By what I understand, you want to sort the matches in descending order with respect to the number of goals. For this particular problem, I think usage of dictionary is not recommended. You can use tuples instead. They will save you the hassle when a team has more than one matches.
Here is the code.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var tuple1 =
            new Tuple<string, string, int>("Man City", "Stoke City", 3);
        var tuple2 =
            new Tuple<string, string, int>("Man Unted", "Liverpool", 2);
        var tuple3 =
            new Tuple<string, string, int>("Barcelona", "Arsenal", 1);

        var championsLeague = new List<Tuple<string, string, int>>();
        championsLeague.Add(tuple1);
        championsLeague.Add(tuple2);
        championsLeague.Add(tuple3);

        //Item3 is the third item from left that mentioned in the definition of the Tuple. ie. Number of goals.
        var lst = championsLeague.OrderByDescending(x => x.Item3)
                           .Select(x=> x.Item1); // Item1 is the first item mentioned in the tuple definition.

        lst.ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine);


    }
}
```

Comment: "I wonder what `Item1` and `Item3` mean"...said every maintainer...ever.

Answer (score 1):

```
        foreach (var firstTeam in dictionary)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{firstTeam.Key}");
            foreach (var secondTeam in firstTeam.Value.OrderByDescending(x => x.Value))
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"#  {secondTeam .Key} -> {secondTeam .Value}");
            }
        }
```

Comment: if you want to use sorting only in printing the result you can use this code

Answer (score 0):

You should try

```
var allMatches = new List<KeyValuePair<KeyValuePair<string, string>, int>>();
foreach(var left in champLeage.Keys)
{
    foreach(var right in left){
        allMatches.Add(new KeyValuePair(new KeyValuePair<left, right>(left, right.Key), right.Value);
    }
} 

foreach(var match in allMatches.OrderByDescending(x => x.Value)){
    ConsoleWriteLine("{0} - {1} : {2}", match.Key.Key, match.Key.Value, match.Value);
}
```

This is not efficient or "pretty". You should use classes. A Match class that have 2 teams and a Result or something like that